# Dynamic key in JSON (or JSONSlurper) in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

Is there a similar notation in Groovy, just like in JavaScript:

```
{

    "name": "Jason Closure"
    "characteristics": {
        "height": ...,
        "weight": ...,
        ...
    }

}
```

where you can refer to an object key like this:

```
def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def char_key = // char_key can be 'height', 'weight',...
content.characteristics[char_key]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can access JSON nodes using array-like notation, e.g.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
    "name": "Jason Closure",
    "characteristics": {
        "height": 10,
        "weight": 20,
    }
}'''

def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def key = 'height'

assert root.characteristics[key] == 10
```

You can also get node value using interpolated GString, e.g.

```
assert root.characteristics."$key" == 10
```

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is when the key is also dynamic, how to fetch the value from the json string, the below is the code snippet for the same, *locator* is the dynamic key in the *jsonText*. if jsonText is **{ "name" : "vijay", "address" : { "country" : "IN", "state" : "Telangana", "city" : "hyderabad" } }**, then *locator* can be *"name"* or *"address.state"* or *"address.city"*. Please let me know if it needs more clarifications.

```
def getJsonProperty(String jsonText,String locator){
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def result = slurper.parseText(jsonText)
    println("responseObject:"+result)
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setVariable("result", result);
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
    return shell.evaluate("result."+locator)
}
```